# Create new excel spreadsheet document using FileStream not MemoryStream in OpenXml

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, spreadsheet, filestream

I am writing code for creating excel spreadsheet using OpenXml. But wanted to use **Filestream** instead of MemoryStream in SpreadSheet.Create() method.

Note: With MemoryStream working correctly but for some reasons I need to get code working with Filestream.

Generating corrupted file when writing code like:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
using (SpreadsheetDocument document = 
SpreadsheetDocument.Create(fs,SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
{
 //worksheet code
}
```

If needed I can post worksheet code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `using` to ensure that the file stream will be closed.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument document = 
SpreadsheetDocument.Create(fs,SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
    {
    //worksheet code
    }
}
```